# How to add one column according to the order after `groupby` in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

My data is like and I want to calculate the `NDCG` metric

```
  pid query title  label  predict  prob
0   1     A     a      0        2   0.9
1   1     A     b      2        0   0.8
2   1     A     c      1        2   0.7
3   2     D     d      3        1   0.8
4   2     D     e      4        2   0.9
```

After `groupby` opration

```
each_pid = data.groupby(data['pid']).apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(['predict', 'prob'], ascending=False))
```

I got a dataframe like this.

```
      pid query title  label  predict  prob  score
pid                                               
1   0   1     A     a      0        2   0.9      6
    2   1     A     c      1        2   0.7     18
    1   1     A     b      2        0   0.8     42
2   4   2     D     e      4        2   0.9    186
    3   2     D     d      3        1   0.8     90
```

Now I want another column names `weight` which's value is according to the order of each group as following.

```
      pid query title  label  predict  prob  score  weight
pid                                               
1   0   1     A     a      0        2   0.9      6    1
    2   1     A     c      1        2   0.7     18    2
    1   1     A     b      2        0   0.8     42    3
2   4   2     D     e      4        2   0.9    186    1
    3   2     D     d      3        1   0.8     90    2
```

And how to get top2 rows of each group like

```
      pid query title  label  predict  prob  score  weight
pid                                               
1   0   1     A     a      0        2   0.9      6    1
    2   1     A     c      1        2   0.7     18    2
2   4   2     D     e      4        2   0.9    186    1
    3   2     D     d      3        1   0.8     90    2
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT. Thanks for @Akshay Kandul and @Allen help. The code works as

```
data = data.groupby(level=0).head(2)
data['weight'] = data.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cumcount function on group by of index level zero

```
each_pid['weight'] = each_pid.groupby(level=[0]).cumcount()
```

output

```
        label  pid  predict  prob query title  weight
pid                                                 
1   0      0    1        2   0.9     A     a       0
    2      1    1        2   0.7     A     c       1
    1      2    1        0   0.8     A     b       2
2   4      4    2        2   0.9     D     e       0
    3      3    2        1   0.8     D     d       1
```

If your really want it to start with 1 then just do this instead:

```
each_pid['weight'] = each_pid.groupby(level=[0]).cumcount()+1
```

output

```
        label  pid  predict  prob query title  weight
pid                                                 
1   0      0    1        2   0.9     A     a       1
    2      1    1        2   0.7     A     c       2
    1      2    1        0   0.8     A     b       3
2   4      4    2        2   0.9     D     e       1
    3      3    2        1   0.8     D     d       2
```

If you need top 2 records of each group you can use this code:

```
print(each_pid.groupby(level=0).head(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on each_pid you've already got, you can use apply to calculate the order:

```
each_pid['weight'] = \
(
     each_pid.groupby(level=0)
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(1,len(x)+1)))
         .values
)

each_pid
Out[263]: 
       pid query title  label  predict  prob  weight
pid                                                 
1   0    1     A     a      0        2   0.9       1
    2    1     A     c      1        2   0.7       2
    1    1     A     b      2        0   0.8       3
2   4    2     D     e      4        2   0.9       1
    3    2     D     d      3        1   0.8       2
```

If you need top 2 of each group, you can do:

```
each_pid.groupby(level=0).head(2)
Out[273]: 
       pid query title  label  predict  prob  weight
pid                                                 
1   0    1     A     a      0        2   0.9       1
    2    1     A     c      1        2   0.7       2
2   4    2     D     e      4        2   0.9       1
    3    2     D     d      3        1   0.8       2
```

Comment: It helps! Thanks, do you know how to get top2 row of each group?